# Configure jboss to use Amazon IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to configure jboss to use [AWS IAM Roles](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/iam/?icmpid=docs_menu) for accessing S3 and SQS. All of the documentation I've seen uses static access and secret keys rather than the dynamic keys that roles allow for.

Is there any documentation on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Create an EC2 instance assigning that Role. Whatever you run any app in that instance will be able to access the AWS resources.

This way you don't need to write any code for security within the application.

Also in your code you don't need to supply any credentials when you assign the role to the EC2 instance.

Comment: It just works automatically? We don't need to do any configuration file changes?

Comment: No configuration needed in the code or in the files. The role that get assigned to the EC2 instance will take care of that automatically. If you notice any error share it here, we can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS there are two approaches to provide permission using AWS IAM to your code to access AWS resources such as S3 and SQS.

- If your code runs in Amazon Compute Services such as EC2, Lambda it is recommended to create a IAM Role with required policies to access S3 & SQS also allowing the Compute Service (EC2, Lambda) to assume that role (Using Trust Relationships). After attaching this role, either to EC2 or Lambda, you can directly use AWS SDK to access S3 and SQS without needing any credentials or access tokens to configure for SDK.

  > For more information, see [Using an IAM Role to Grant Permissions to
  >   Applications Running on Amazon EC2 Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html).
- If your code runs on premise or external to the Amazon infrastructure, you need to create a IAM user with required policies and also create access keys (Access Key ID & Secret Key) and [initialize](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html) SDK to allow access to S3 or SQS as shown below.

  `var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
   accessKeyId: 'akid', secretAccessKey: 'secret'
  });`

Comment: Exposing AccessKey and SecretKey in code is a very bad practice and not recommended.

Comment: @Kannaiyan The question is configuring JBoss server to acess IAM roles which happens from server side. There are no mentions about using client code with access keys and secrets. The code example shown is for NodeJS for server. Hope this clarifies your comment.

Comment: @Kannaiyan can you please explain the purpose of having Access keys and Secret keys? If it cannot be used in server side as mentioned in above snippet, I believe there will be no use cases for access keys and secret keys. However if we are looking at the client side, the story is different. But as you can see, this is a server side.

Comment: @RumeshEranga Use with CLI (storing those keys secure). Even then it needs to be reset at a certain frequency to protect your infrastructure. Having it in the code is one of the simple and dangerous ways to risk your infrastructure. Also if you reset your keys, your whole systems depending upon those keys will be down, you need to code for redundant and lot more there to architect and that is not good to expose in codebase or storing anywhere in the database.

Comment: @Kannaiyan Can you relate where does it states to hardcode it in source code? The code snippet(From AWS Docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html) is for the understanding of the audience, that the access key and secret is need to be initialized in code in server-side. The actual key or secret can be coming from Key Vault or Environmental variables depending on the ability of the audience. Since this is not a question about how to secure credentials in server, I haven't included all the scenarios on securing credentials in server-side.